# android products workflow for productivity

Tags: android, workflow, product

in our company we are creating a product that is sold to different customers only changing visuals aspects (logos, trademarks, text, etc ...). We doubt how to handle this as we need to maintain a base (with their testings) and customized versions of these products (different package name and some modifications asides).
The more difficult for us is we handle this with Git and projects libraries that need to keep together. We need to keep easy to create new products and maintain updates for each one quickly

which workflow do you recommended to handle this? we have a mix of git + submodules + branches + libraries projects, but it's hard to create an android libproyect base

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question so if you could write some more info it would be useful for others to help you. The part I understood was the problem of managing multiple projects that have same code but different resources and manifest files. On our project we had a similar problem developing for 3 different servers where code would stay the same but links, api keys and package names would need to change, even logo images might need to be different sometimes adding "integration icon/development icon" etc. What I did in this case was to create one Android library project where all the code and resources that are shared are stored and in our case 3 other projects that reference the library and have special res/drawable folder and strings in value folder where api keys and other settings are stored. This turned out to be great fit for our purposes since you can just pick a run configuration for project to be run and Android will load required resources. You could do this for any number of projects without any files being duplicated and taking space in your git repository. This approach actually allows you to let your designers change drawables for diffident projects by putting different images in folders without or with just a little involvement from developers. If you are skill full you could even write some ant scripts that build and sign projects for them so they can test on devices to see how real app looks.

Comment: after ask,  I took a look to  Google IO videos and I  found this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0 The New Android SDK Build System , that was exactly what I needed : flavors, releases, testing and debug builds, all in one . For now I will try your approach, but the real hard task is making "changes" for specifics clients, and dont break the base android library.

Comment: This approach is great if you are not changing code for different clients, just settings and resources. Although at the start of the project we had to change small parts of code for different builds and it's also doable like this if you set manifest files to target specific classes in current project and use Inheritance where appropriate. Thank you for the link I haven't taken a look at 2013 lectures yet but this does seem like one of the most interesting.